# RTCPeerConnection.generateCertificate() is returning an empty object

Tags: webrtc, mozilla, client-certificates, rtcpeerconnection

Here is the code (browser Chrome on Ubuntu):

```
   RTCPeerConnection.generateCertificate(
            {              name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
                  modulusLength: 2048,
                 publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
                           hash: "SHA-256" })
           .then 
             ( function(cert) {
                 console.log("typeof: " + typeof(cert));
                  console.log("S: " + JSON.stringify(cert));
               }, 
               function(err) {
                   console.log("E: " + err);
               } 
             );
```

It displays:

```
   typeof: object
   S: {}
```

Actually this is almost the exact code from [Mozilla site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/generateCertificate)

Also, conforms to the WebRTC  [specs Section 4.9](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-rtccertificate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate isn't serializable. If you add a `console.log(cert);` you'll see something along the lines of `RTCCertificate { expires: 1595444355114 }`. That is intentional, you can not export the key like you can in webcrypto. And there is no toJSON

Comment: Is there an API to get fingerprint of the certificate? This is anyway available in the sdp as a=fingerprint?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
cert.getFingerprints()[0].value.toUpperCase().trim();

https://pi.pe/p/genCertTest.html

is a page that exercises generateCertificate()